# ASP.NET Default Membership and Role Provider API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

Suppose I have the following in my web.config:

```
<profile enabled="true">
<providers>
...
<add name="Phone" type="System.String" defaultValue="" />
```

I would like this variable to be `unique` just like you would specify a unique in sql server or whatever, meaning there can be one unique phone number for all membership users.

Is this possible? I've been searching for a while for a fix but the only solution I can find is to create a new table just for storing unique numbers.

Is there a way to specify a unique attribute to a profile property using ASP.NET 4.0?
Thank you!

Comment: What variable are you talking about?

Comment: Hi Shoban, I am talking about "Phone". - Which can be accessed using Profile.Phone

Comment: Is it just me? I think you have misunderstood the meaning of `<add name="....` .. this is not a user property. Its provider settings.

Comment: It's a user property...This is accessible on each membership user when using the ProfileCommon class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this -- rather than trying to shoe-horn it into the Profile model -- is probably to create a new table indexed by UserId, with Phone as a column of its own, with a unique index.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add properties to the default profile provider by adding xml elements to the config file. You need to [implement a customer Membership User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx) type with the properties that you need.

**edit**

The generated Membership User based on the config you create is not backed by a database schema you can work with. All of the properties are serialized and stashed in a [single BLOB column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478906/asp-net-membership-how-do-i-add-a-new-property-to-aspnet-profile), which means you can't make any of them required, create an index based on them, or query directly against them in SQL. I strongly encourage you to implement your own User & provider so that you have control over its persistence and behavior.

Comment: Hi RyanR, You can add properties to the default profile provider, I already have a fully functional website with properties added via web.config to my users (ie: firstname/lastname/phone etc...)